# How to setup a Xen domU with multiple subnets on one interface?

Tags: networking, xen

I have a host (host1.example.com) with the following IPs:

```
IP: 10.0.0.6
Subnet: 255.255.255.192
Gateway: 10.0.0.1
Broadcast: 10.0.0.63
```

```
IP: 10.0.1.9
Subnet: 255.255.255.248
Broadcast: 10.0.1.15
```

How to setup host1.example.com to host dom0 on both subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple network interfaces and attach them to different bridges in Domain-U's profile:

vif=['mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,bridge=eth0', 'mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx,bridge=eth1']

If you want one network card of DomU have two IPs, that's not a problem related to Xen:

You can create another configuration for ethx (let's use eth0): eth0:0.
eth0 uses device eth0, and eth0:0 uses device eth0:0. Then you can give eth0 and eth0:0 different IP addresses, broadcast subnet, DNS, etc. Then you can change Linux route table by ip command: http://fclose.com/p/linux-command/8-ip/#lbBB